# MPMoviePlayerController Not Working - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

Ok so I have a view controller which I want to load a video file in MPMoviePlayerController on viewDidLoad. I am using the following code and when it runs, I get absolutely nothing. The code I am using is as follows:

```swift
import UIKit
import iAd
import MediaPlayer


class VideoPlayer: UIViewController {

    var moviePlayer : MPMoviePlayerController?


    func playVideo() {
        let url = NSURL (string: "http://jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v")
        moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
        if let player = moviePlayer {
            player.view.frame = self.view.bounds
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.scalingMode = .AspectFill
            self.view.addSubview(player.view)
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

playVideo()
    }
}
```

There is a segue from the mainViewController to the VideoPlayerViewController which is triggered when the play button is pressed. I know that the files are correctly linked as I have set up iAds in the file.

I will attach a few screenshots below:
[image: What I get when the simulator runs]
[image: The Debug Console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not in the code that you provided. it is somewhere else in your project.
I just created a new singleView Project pasted your code. put playVideo in viewDidLoad. Run it and it is showing the video when the app starts.

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var moviePlayer : MPMoviePlayerController?

func playVideo() {
    let url = NSURL (string: "http://jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v")
    moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
    if let player = moviePlayer {
        player.view.frame = self.view.bounds
        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.scalingMode = .AspectFill
        self.view.addSubview(player.view)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    playVideo()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Adding a screenshot of a working app

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: thanks for the help. Any ideas where to look for issues? Also, would you know how I could get the done buttons etc to show up?

Comment: Look for issues: Try to remove iAds and see if it works without it. There is a multiple ways to add buttons. You can set up a listener via NotificationCenter and display a Done button when the video finish playing it will send MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification

Comment: Thanks. It's definitely with that view controller setup as I put it into another empty view controller I had linked up to another button and it worked fine. Think I'll just remove that vc and create a new one.

Comment: Cool! If you think that I helped you to solve the problem, please mark the answer as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Video will not run if we add --var moviePlayer : MPMoviePlayerController?-- in method instead of global variable. why so?

Comment: The scope of MPMoviePlayerController should be whole viewContoller not just a method in it; movie player has to substitute the whole view.